# Add users to group in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I am filled with chagrin having to ask this, but I can't figure out how to add users in GitLab.  I get to the screen where it allows me to add new members as follows:

> From my Group page -> click the 'members' icon on the toolbar along
>   the left edge -> click 'Add Members' expando button -> enter username
>   in 'Find existing member by name' or 'People' fields and get no
>   results.

The 'People' field auto-populates with a bunch of names I don't recognize.  But won't let me find a user who has registered by username or actual name.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What version?  These instructions are for gitlab community edition on ubuntu; the deb was named gitlab_7.4.3-omnibus.5.1.0.ci-1_amd64:

1. Login
2. Click the gears icon (top right) to enter the Admin area
3. Click the Groups link (top center) to enter the Groups page
4. Click the name of the group you wish to extend ("Mygroup")
5. Look at the right side of the screen; if you have the right privs you should see "Add user(s) to the group:"
6. Type the first few letters of the user name into the box, a drop-down should appear so you can select the user.

HTH

Comment: Okay, I tried this but it still won't show the usernames of my colleagues who have signed up with GitLab.

Comment: Checking if we're on the same page: I run a private gitlab instance on my ubuntu 14.04 server and I had to add users manually (they cannot sign up); are you asking about that setup, or an account & repos on https://about.gitlab.com ?

Comment: Nope, we're not on the same page because I'm a moron.  I am logging into the main GitLab website.  I was hoping it would host a repository like GitHub but do it privately for free.  I was also hoping they would send me gummy bears and cookies every week for free.

Comment: Okay, so it turns out the user who I was trying to add created an account on GitHub, not GitLab, so we were both idiots.  It was completely straight forward once they actually created an account on GitLab.

Answer (score 9):

GitLab Changed a lot since then, the option for adding members

1.Click the Group
2.In Left pane, Select option **Group Information**
3.Select **Members**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Gitlab Latest Version Solution**

It is very simple now. Just watch those steps:

- Go to your project or group. I mean where you want to add members.
- on your left bottom **Side Navigation Bar** you could see **Settings**.
- If you hover mouse on that, you would see **Members** option. On the second line.
- Click on there and you are all set to add members, their role, expiry date etc...

Happy Coding...